# How to generate entities to custom folder with jhipster:entity?

Tags: yeoman, jhipster

I would like to generate my models/entities into a custom folder/package and not to domain. Is this possible with the entity generator command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Of course, refactoring your domain classes is just a matter of dragging/dropping those files to another directory, if you have a decent IDE, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I figured this would be the case, the only thing that made me hesitant of moving the classes was, that maybe liquibase would need them to be in the domain package itself and not in a sub package, but from your answer I would think this shouldn't be a problem then. Still I might take a look at the jhipster source to find out how much work would be to implement this feature, I would really like to have this, not sure how other feel about it :)

Answer (score 1):

it wasn't as easy for me. After refactoring the entity class, I had to change all the classes and .js files generated by jhipster.  For example, @RequestMapping in  the rest controller has to be changed by adding the new path to the entity (@RequestMapping("/myEntity") becomes @RequestMapping("newpackage/myEntity")).